# Div is not displaying as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HI People I am trying to create a slide from left testinomial but it not coming properly it has two in one row but the third one is coming in place of 4th one and the space of third one is left blank
CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*clearfixes*/

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.main-container {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 1000px;
  line-height: 170%;
  margin: 25px auto 25px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container_scroll {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
}
/*animation element*/

.animation-element {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}
/*animation element sliding left*/

.animation-element.slide-left {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.in-view {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
/*animation slide left styled for testimonials*/

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 0% 1.5% 3% 1.5%;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 15px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:hover,
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:active{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(odd) {
  width: 48.5%;
  margin: 0% 1.5% 3.0% 0%;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(even) {
  width: 48.5%;
  margin: 0% 0% 3.0% 1.5%;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .header{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .left{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .right{
  float: left;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial img {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial h3 {
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial h4 {
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .content {
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .rating{}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial i {
  color: #aaa;
  margin-right: 5px;
}



/*media queries for small devices*/
@media screen and (max-width: 678px){
  /*testimonials*/
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(odd),
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(even){
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  }
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .right,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .left,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .content,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .rating{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial img{
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container_scroll cf">
    <!-- testimonial one -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
        <h3>America's Gold Expert.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Get the proven trust and experience of our Chief Numismatic Consultant Mike Fuljenz. With nearly 40 years in the numismatic field, he is an award-winning author and noted gold expert; he is also considered one of the world's authorities on coin grading and the rare gold coin market. Contact us for free award winning advice and information. <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--testimonial two -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
          <h3>Demand Today. Legacy Tomorrow. </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>Our market makes efforts and innovating book distribution strategies create ongoing education, awareness, and demand for Select Four coin types among collectors and investors today supporting the desirability of your collection for your heirs and the collectors of tomorrow.
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--testimonial three -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
            <h3>Expert Recommendations.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The artistically acclaimed Gold Eagles are essential to any estate collection of U.S. legal tender coins. For many collectors, the $25 Gold Eagle is the key coin, having the lowest total mintage almost every year since 1986.
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--testimonial four -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
          <h3>Professional Buying Team.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Having a portfolio buying team in your cornerensures that you get advance word on important high-quality coind as they become available which could save you big money on a vital coin purchase while helpig you fill those tough holes in your sets or collection.
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
     <!--testimonial five -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
          <h3>Specialized Collection Strategies.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> With an expert in your corner, you'll learn the "inside track" strategies that have served our customers nationwide in building premier collections and completing sets, while acquiring some of the rarest, select Liberty Double Eagles, Indian gold coins and Commemorative gold coins available today.
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Script:

```
  var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? fiddle?

Comment: @Radmation I am pretty much trying to achieve this http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwEaQM

Comment: I recommend looking a wow.js (just google it) it will save you time and effort. http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: @RadmationI did and this looks easier then wow.js to me I have almost done it but there is some glich in CSS

Comment: I had a similar problem with divis that "auto organize" them self in view port... I solve it by adding each one to a container div with default height and width, so like the example you show, the fit like cells...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing an html page so I can inspect element and play with the css..

Comment: @Radmation Ya I understand but here is a scenario if I reduce the content of 1st div then the third one comes right under it I know it is CSS but I am not able to grab it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue of

> clear:left;

The height of each boxes are different. that's why the float is not work well.
please set a min-height related with the largest animation-element height

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the look you are after, but if you add:

```
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(odd) { clear: left; }
```

I think you get closer.